# How to trim pyspark schema output

Tags: python, pyspark

My pyspark dataframe has the following schema...

`DataFrame[ExternalData: struct<provider:string,data:string,modality:array<string>>]`

If I write (where `sdf` is my pyspark dataframe)..

`sdf.schema`

I get...

```
StructType([StructField('ExternalData', StructType([StructField('provider', StringType(), True), StructField('data', StringType(), True), StructField('modality', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True)]), True)])
```

How can I get just the below?

```
StructType([StructField('provider', StringType(), True), StructField('data', StringType(), True), StructField('modality', ArrayType(StringType(), True), True)])
```

There is a subtle difference in that the `ExternalData` `StructType` and `StructField` has been removed. The reason I need to do this is because the system I'm integrating parquet with expects parquet schema in this format, where `ExternalData` field and struct is passed elsewhere.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Can you provide input (couple of rows) of the existing dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

Your DataFrame schema:

```
root
 |-- ExternalData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- provider: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- modality: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Selecting all the sub-columns of `ExternalData` to get the desired output

```
sdf = sdf.select("ExternalData.*")
sdf.printSchema()
```

**Output:**

```
root
 |-- provider: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modality: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```